# How to reset form data in header without redirecting ?

Tags: php, apache

Does anyone know how to reset form data in header without redirecting  cause when refresh the page auto posting form data. redirecting takes more time. any solution for this problem ?

Comment: use ajax to submit ...then

Comment: "any solution for this problem" yeah do a redirect like you should. The mention of redirect being slow is nonsense.

Comment: Do you mean a "reset" button on the form that clears all values? If you don't want to refresh the page then you will need to do this with JavaScript. jQuery will do this will a couple of lines of code. Or if you just want to discard form values after it's been submitted, you can do unset($_POST);

Comment: yes im going covert to ajax submit, thanks   @gazareth thanks, unset thing is working

Answer (score 1):

This line will clear all POST data in your PHP without having to redirect. Be careful, make sure you do everything you want to do with the POST data before calling it.

```
unset($_POST);
```